# How to use a delared variables inside a script?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, integration, inline

I want to integrate this payment gateway into a project, is an inline js... Now I have declared variables I want to use inside the script but when I call the variables in the script, the script will no longer function. Can someone help me out, please?

```
$email = "example@example.com";
$amount = "10000";
$phone = "080000000000";
   <!-- place below the html form -->
    <script>
        function payWithPaystack() {
            var handler = PaystackPop.setup({
                key: 'xxxxxx',
                email: $email,
                amount: $amount,
                currency: "NGN",
                ref: '' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1), // generates a pseudo-unique reference. Please replace with a reference you generated. Or remove the line entirely so our API will generate one for you
                metadata: {
                    custom_fields: [{
                        display_name: "example",
                        variable_name: "example",
                        value: $phone
                    }]
                },
                callback: function(response) {

                    window.location.href = 'initialize.php?ref=' + response.reference&email=$email&amount=$amount;

                },
                onClose: function() {
                    alert('window closed');
                }
            });
            handler.openIframe();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Where did you declare variables? Is it PHP?

Comment: at top

I included <?php    ?> though